# Minipage overlapping with text that follows

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm trying to replicate the following layout that I have in a Word version of the paper:

[image: This is what I want to get in LaTeX.]

There are two code sections side by side with the code balanced between the two. The code won't fit into a single column, so I used this way to get it to stay on the same page. The caption would be under.

I tried doing this, but unfortunately, that kind of works, but not quite. It produces the two columns, but there are issues:

[image: LaTeX version of what I got.]

So first thing is the columns do not align with the text columns (red lines). I think it probably has to do with my minipage somehow.

Secondly, it overlaps with text that follows (that biography box should be later on!). Makes me feel like it does not recognize that the minipage is there and renders the text anyways.

Here is a code snippet that does this (I use same syntax in my file):

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\newcommand{\us}{\char`_}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{base}{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    multicols=2,
    breaklines=true
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{minipage}[5cm]{\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption=Migration,style=base,captionpos=b]
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;



\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%


\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I hope someone can hint which way I should proceed here.

Comment: Can you get us some compilable code? This is a mess up there ;-)

Comment: Put `\noindent` right before the minipage.

Comment: @Johannes_B, thanks! The \noindent fixed the indent... I added a snippet that compiles and does the same thing (a MWE?).

Comment: I can get it to not overlap if I put \begin{figure}... \end{figure} around the minipage. But then the whole thing just appears on its own page.

Comment: @Mewa get rid of the `minipage` and use the starred `figure*` to enclose your listing. It will be moved to the top of the following page but you won't have the problems that you mention.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, that didn't work. It is on its own page (in the center of it), and all the text is elsewhere.

Comment: @Mewa did you use the starred version as in `\begin{figure*}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption=Migration,style=base,captionpos=b]
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure*}`? Notice that it is `figure*` with an asterisk.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yeah I did, but it turns out I needed much more dummy text to see the effect.Thanks! That works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `minipage` and enclose the listing inside a `figure*`; it will be moved to the top of the following page but you won't have the problems that you are experiencing now:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{base}{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    multicols=2,
    breaklines=true
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\us}{\char`_}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption=Migration,style=base,captionpos=b]
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
int a;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure*}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ``\chardef\us`\_`` instead of `\newcommand\us..`? (In case this suggestion is correct, I don't know what's de benefit of this, just that it seems to be the appropiate tool.)

Comment: @Manuel that's part of the original code. I don't know its purpose and it was not my suggestion.

Comment: True, sorry, I thought it was yours :)

Comment: @Manuel, that was the result of some quick Googlin' in an attempt to spend less time typing in \char`_ for all of the underscores. I'll check your method out tomorrow morning :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this. This uses `figure*` to produce a double-column float. To centre the caption, `caption` is used so that the `figure*` caption can be assigned to the `lstlisting` captions rather than regular figures.

[image: multicolumn listing with justified caption]

[image: listing in list of listings]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\newcommand{\us}{\char`_}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{base}{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  multicols=2,
  breaklines=true,
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lstlistoflistings
  \begin{figure*}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,style=base]
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
      int a;
    \end{lstlisting}
    \captionsetup{type=lstlisting}
    \caption{Migration}
  \end{figure*}

  \kant[1-20]

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

Edited in light of Gonzalo Medina's comment concerning the format of captions for this class. `justification=justified` justifies captions and `singlelinecheck=false` prevents those containing only one line from being centred anyway.

Comment: The `caption` package and `IEEEtran` are not fully compatible. Why using `\captionsetup{type=lstlisting}
    \caption{Migration}` and not the `caption` key for `lstlisting` (as in my answer and the OP's original code) which doesn't require the use of the `caption` package?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I thought that the OP wanted the caption under the two-column listing of code?

Comment: Ah, I see. This might indeed be the case and my answer doesn't cover it. I'll delete my comments shortly.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Whether that's what the OP meant or not, I'm not now sure. (That's just how I read the question.) In any case, is there a better way to do this? I've not really any experience with `listings`. However, I did look to see if there was a way to do this with the `caption` key which the OP had used and couldn't find anything which looked promising in the manual. [Although I posted my answer 30 minutes after yours, I didn't actually see yours. I had to read the docs for `listings` to get as far as I did.]

Comment: Not really. One could try to redefine some internals using something like    `\end{lstlisting}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\ext@lstlisting{lol}
    \renewcommand\@captype{lstlisting}
    \caption{Migration}
    \makeatother
  \end{figure*}` but this is just a provisional version (the counter will be missing in the caption). In any case, notice that the `caption` package changes the caption alignment (`IEEEtran` won't center captions even if single-lined while `caption` enforces this).

Comment: I did a caption under both columns (so whole page wide) by adding another \begin{lstlisting}[caption = blahblahlbah]\end{listing} after the first one. The numbering seemed to work out.

Comment: @Mewa Interesting. Does it only increment the counter when you actually have a caption, maybe?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina will know....

Comment: @cfr, yeah it seems so. I'm not sure if that will cause other problems, or whether IEEE will get upset if I submit it like that, but for the time being it seems to be what I want.